# Applescript to select Safari import options

Tags: applescript

This [applescript](https://gist.github.com/Aneureka/41e4ee6ecb797bc97d20a44927d3dcbe) automates the process of importing Chrome bookmarks, history & passwords to Safari. But, I like to skip the password. How can I do that? Here is the script:

```
    -- close google chrome to perform importing 
do shell script "killall \"Google Chrome\" || echo \"Google Chrome is not running.\""

do shell script "killall Safari || echo \"Safari is not running.\""
tell application "Safari" to activate

tell application "System Events" to set visible of application process "Safari" to false

-- import history, bookmarks, passwords from google chrome to safari
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    delay 0.5
    log "Syncing..."
    tell menu item "Import From" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        tell menu "Import From"
            click menu item "Google Chrome.app…"
        end tell
    end tell
    keystroke return
    log "Complete sync"
end tell

-- close safari
do shell script "killall Safari || echo \"Safari is not running.\""

-- restore chrome closed tabs and minimize window in background
delay 0.5
log "Opening chrome in background"
do shell script "open -a \"Google Chrome\" --args --restore-last-session --no-startup-window"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. The point of importing all the history to Safari is that I can keep all my browsing history in Safari. And I can access them also from my phone.